# How to enable XP Setup to offer Repair

Tags: windows-xp, repair-install

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XP CD doesn't offer repair option](https://superuser.com/questions/35290/xp-cd-doesnt-offer-repair-option)

Randomly, some versions of XP will not offer the Repair part during setup (after accepting the EULA, before selecting the hard drive). It doesn't seem to have anything in common, so I was just wondering, what criteria does the Windows XP setup look for to determine if it can do a Repair Install or if it just allows you to do a clean install?